# Silverlight control for visualizing events over time?

Tags: silverlight, controls

We are looking at implementing a Silverlight project to provide users with visualization of events over time and so I have started to look for a control that will let me do so. The inspiration for our project is a visualization The Guardian has done: http://www.guardian.co.uk/world/interactive/2011/mar/22/middle-east-protest-interactive-timeline

So, can anyone think of a control/project that will allow us to do something like this?

Comment: It looks very nice.  I can think of "Carousel Control" which is marginally similar to this.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/carousel.aspx  and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/VideoCarouselControl.aspx

Comment: Yes, that's what I've been thinking as well. Will probably have to do some serious modification to such a control to build this myself... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite as visually impressive as the Guardian example, but there's a [WPF & Silverlight Timeline Control](http://timeline.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex.

The [Microsoft Expression Gallery](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com) might also have some additional examples.